# Is there any public domain Controller Area Network trace data from a real vehicle?

Tags: data-request, computing

I am developing an emulator for the [Controller Area Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus) protocol in motor vehicles, and I am wondering if there is any openly available trace data for this application.

Answer (score 2):

I found this research paper and in the abstract, the authors write that they use trace data from CAN. You should contact them and ask them to share the data with you.

Here is the [research paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5196185).